# SQL FULL JOIN SYNTAX ISSUES

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a full join in SQL but I keep getting this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma…yroll P ON A.project_id = P.project_id' at line 1`

This is the query. I can't figure out what is wrong!

```
SELECT A.quantity, A.unit_price, P.paid_amount,  FROM assets A FULL JOIN payroll P ON A.project_id = P.project_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`, so I presume you are using MySQL.  Please tag your question appropriately.  Unless it is the comma before the `FROM`, but I think that would generate a different error.

Comment: OK. I'm using MSYQL!

Answer (score 1):

`FULL JOIN` is almost never necessary.  Why not just do this?

```
SELECT A.quantity, A.unit_price, P.paid_amount
FROM assets A LEFT JOIN
     payroll P
     ON A.project_id = P.project_id;
```

Or, if you might have different projects in each table:

```
SELECT a.quantity, a.unit_price, pr.paid_amount
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN
     assets a
     ON a.project_id = p.project_id LEFT JOIN
     payroll pr
     ON a.project_id = p.project_id
WHERE a.project_id IS NOT NULL or pr.project_id IS NOT NULL;
```

(Presumably if you have `project_id`, then you have a `projects` table with one row per project.)

Even in databases that support `FULL JOIN`, the two `LEFT JOIN`s is likely to have better performance than the `FULL JOIN`.